# How to connect local database to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

Since i am new to Google App Engine, I am using MySQL database locally and I am running a sample application in Google App Engine. But i need to use database also using Google Cloud SQL, I referred some details in the Google developer zone and found some information in connecting Google Cloud SQL using googlemysql connection

I have used a sample code for MySQL connection

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
                // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://"
                // prefix.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
                url = "jdbc:google:mysql://azk-net:your-instance-name/guestbook?user=root";
            } else {
                // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root";

                // Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
                // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/guestbook?user=root
            }
```

but the thing is i cannot create instance name for my project. In local it is working correctly but i have deployed in the google app engine i am getting error since instance name is not available

I am creating the instance name in the Google Cloud SQL but it is not creating it requires billing.

can anyone help me to connect the database from local to Google Cloud SQL by writing connection properties for accessing database from Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no free quota for Google Cloud SQL, you have to enable billing to use it

> Google offers two billing plans for Cloud SQL: Packages and Per Use. More information on pricing for Google Cloud SQL can be found on [the Cloud SQL Pricing page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing).